# Where do $p$-adic numbers and $p$-Sylow theory both appear?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, number-theory, p-adic-number-theory, sylow-theory

Both [$p$-adic numbers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/P-adic_number) and [$p$-Sylow theory](http://groupprops.subwiki.org/wiki/Sylow_subgroup) are by design "arithmetic" ways of "localizing," so it stands to reason they might be in cahoots in certain contexts. Are they?

Answer (score 11):

In the context of abelian torsion groups, Sylow subgroups correspond to the summands occurring in the torsion decomposition as per [structure theorem](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/22646/structure-theorem-for-abelian-torsion-groups-that-are-not-finitely-generated). In particular, as additive groups,

$$\frac{\bf Q}{\bf Z}\cong \bigoplus_p \frac{{\bf Q}_p}{{\bf Z}_p}.$$

The [Prufer $p$-groups](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pr%C3%BCfer_group) ${\bf Z}(p^\infty)\cong{\bf Q}_p/{\bf Z}_p$ and the $p$-adic integers ${\bf Z}_p$ are [Pontryagin duals](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pontryagin_duality) of each other. This decomposition is the number field analogue of partial fraction decomposition present in function fields, which I elaborate over at [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/399633/how-to-use-results-from-partial-fractions/399665#399665), illustrating this is a [global](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Global_field) phenomenon.

---

The connection between nilpotence and Sylow subgroups allows [zeta function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_zeta_functions) techniques to study  finitely-generated torsion-free nilpotent (i.e. $\frak T$-)groups, in particular [lattice-of-subgroup](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lattice_of_subgroups) structure and asymptotic analysis of [subgroup growth](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subgroup_growth), via [local Euler products](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler_product). The $p$-adic numbers come into play when local zeta *integrals* are used. See [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/efuO1.png), source being the first reference below.

- *Zeta Functions of Groups and Rings* - du Sautoy & Woodward
- *Lectures on Profinite Topics in Group Theory* - Klopsch, Nikolov & Voll

---

Here is a connection I have not seen mentioned anywhere. Let $W_{p^n}$ be the [wreath power](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wreath_product) $$W_{p^n}=\underbrace{C_p\wr C_p\wr\cdots\wr C_p}_n.$$

The Sylow $p$-subgroups of $S_n$, where $n=a_kp^k+\cdots+a_1p+a_0$ is $n$'s $p$-adic expansion, are

$$a_kW_{p^k}\oplus\cdots\oplus a_1 W_{p}\oplus a_0 W_1,$$

up to isomorphism, where $W_1$ is the trivial group and $$mG:=\underbrace{G\oplus G\oplus\cdots\oplus G}_m.$$ This can be proven by computing the order of the above subgroup in $S_n$. Note that $W_{p^n}$ is also the automorphism group of the [$p$-ary rooted tree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/K-ary_tree) of depth $n$. Incidentally, the topology on ${\bf Z}_p$ is that of an infinite-depth rooted $p$-ary tree (see [*Pictures of Ultrametric Spaces*](https://www.colby.edu/math/faculty/Faculty_files/hollydir/Holly01.pdf) by Holly).

As an aside, in [*Tree Representations of Galois Groups*](http://arxiv.org/abs/math/0009256), Boston conjecturally notes that $p$-adic [Galois](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Galois_group) [representations](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Group_representation) into matrix groups convey very little information whereas $p$-adic Galois reps into tree automorphism groups should convey a lot, according to [Hausdorff dimension](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hausdorff_dimension).

Since [isometries](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Isometry) of ${\bf Z}_p$ correspond to automorphisms of the underlying tree topology, the isometry group is given by ${\sf Iso}({\bf Z}_p)\cong\varprojlim W_{p^n}$. The torsion subset is a subgroup isomorphic to $\varinjlim W_{p^n}$. The Sylow $p$-subgroup of ${\sf Sym}({\bf Z})\ge\varinjlim S_n$ is also seen to be $\varinjlim W_{p^n}$. Its topological closure (in terms of pointwise convergence of functions) is isomorphic to $\varprojlim W_{p^n}$. (See [direct](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Direct_limit) / [inverse](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverse_limit) limits.) (At least I'm pretty sure about that last claim. Still trying to pin down my intuition into a proof.)

Answer (score 4):

Here's one reasonably simple link:  In terms of Sylow theory, a nice home for generalization is the land of profinite groups, where you have directly analogous Sylow theorems (with directly analogous proofs).  Among profinite groups there is the canonical $\widehat{\mathbb{Z}}$, the profinite completion of $\mathbb{Z}$ and free profinite group of rank 1.  The decomposition
$$
\widehat{\mathbb{Z}}\cong \prod_p \mathbb{Z}_p
$$
shows that the $p$-adic integers are simply the $p$-Sylow subgroup of this very canonical group.

Comment: It should be noted that while the usual definition of $p$-Sylow subgroup is "maximal $p$-subgroup" (applicable to finite and infinite groups alike), in the profinite context the better definition is "maximal *pro*-$p$ subgroup" (which is what's used here).